# Accessing a method from an object

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a simple question. If my class has a `vector` of other class objects, and I want to access a method which is in one of those objects, but not using the `[]` operator, then how can I do it? I've got code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Sample
{
    int label;
    std::vector<int> int_vector;
public:
    int getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }
    void writeDown()
    {
        int i=0;
        for(auto it=int_vector.begin(); it!=int_vector.end();it++,i++)
        {
            std::cout<<(*it)<<std::endl;
        }  
    }
    Sample(int label, int tab[10])
    {
        int i=0;
        this->label=label;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            int_vector.push_back(tab[i]);
        }
    }
    ~Sample()
    {
        std::cout<<"Object has been removed"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Dataset
{
public:
    std::vector<Sample *> vectorOfSamples;
    Dataset(Sample *sample)
    {
        vectorOfSamples.push_back(sample);
    }
};    




int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tab[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Sample sample(5,tab);
    Dataset dataset(&sample);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        dataset.vectorOfSamples.push_back(new Sample(i, tab));
    }
    for (auto it=dataset.vectorOfSamples.begin(); it!=dataset.vectorOfSamples.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout<<it.getLabel()<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And when I do it, `g++` gives me this:

[image]

Changing it to `it->getLabel()` gives me this:

[image]

How can I make it work?

Comment: Do not post screenshots in your question. Copy and paste the error messages, instead.

Comment: How can I copy and paste from `cmd`?

Comment: @LogicStuff I don't think your first one works; `->` has higher precedence than `*`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (auto it=dataset.vectorOfSamples.begin(); it!=dataset.vectorOfSamples.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout<<(*it)->getLabel()<<std::endl;
}
```

You have to dereference your iterator.